# Firebase Storage custom domain without hosting

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-storage

I'm currently creating a website that is hosted on a vServer from another provider where you can upload images. I'm uploading the images to Firebase Storage. Can I change the domain when I rightclick -> view graphic that is my own domain? I already know that you can change the domain of firebase when you host the website there, but I don't want to host the website there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to control the URL that is used to serve files directly from **Firebase Storage**. The download URLs are controlled by Firebase and always are based on your bucket/project name.

But Firebase server-side logic is a fairly thin wrapper around **Google Cloud Storage**, and you **can** set up a [custom domain for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http#cname). You can ignore the parts that talk about this as being specific to hosting a web site there, as a web site on Google Cloud Storage is not much more than the files it consists of, you can apply the same to hosting other files. That should allow you to control the domain from which your files are served.

The final alternative would be to host the files on **Firebase Hosting**, which means they'll be served from a CDN with many global end points. The main difference here is that Firebase Hosting is typically better suited for files *you* generate, and not so much for files that your users generate.